# Поиск в json, просмотр ответа и запись его в excel

Tags: python, json

Здраствуйте.
Я делаю запрос к сайту и получаю ответ json. Как пример (не полный):

```
"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
      "Title": "Silver Sword",  # Это мне нужно вытащить
      "Offer": {
        "OfferID": "111",
        "Price": {
          "Currency": "Gold",
          "Amount": 0.1  # Это добавить в ячейку для подсчёта общей стоимости всех таких же предметов
        },
        "Fee": null,
        "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
      },
      "MarketPrice": null,
      "InstantPrice": null,
      "ClassID": "0:222"
    },
```

Таких ответ = количеству предметов у меня в инвентаре. Они могу быть одинаковыми по ['Title']. Т.е если у меня 10 Silver Sword в инвентаре, то json ответ выдаст 10 блоков с одним и тем же ['Title'].
Задача у меня стоит такая. Каждый найденный предмет с одинаковым названием не дублировать ниже, а просто прибавлять +1 к количеству в соседней строке excel. Как вариант делать это через:

```
if weapon.find('Silver Sword') != -1: # поиск по названию
    sheet_active[row][4].value = 'Silver Swords' # запись в ячейку.
    sheet_active[row][5].value = sum(weapon_price) # попытка суммировать сумму (неудачная)
```

И тогда повторной записи внизу не будет, но! В таком случае ячейка закрепляется за предметов и если она из инвентаря исчезнет, то в таблице будет пробел...
Так же нужно в след. ячейку суммировать сумму этих предметов...

```
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl

r = requests.get(url4, headers=headers)  # Offers Status
    get_request = json.loads(r.text)
    row = 3
    for item in get_request['Items']:
        weapon = item['Title']
        weapon_price = item['Offer']['Price']['Amount']
        if weapon.find('Silver Sword') != -1:  # поиск по названию
            sum = 0
            sheet_active[row][4].value = 'Silver Swords'  # запись в ячейку.
            sheet_active[row][5].value = sum(weapon_price)
        elif item in get_request['Items']:
            row + 1
            sum = 0
            sheet_active[row][4].value = 'Gold Sword'
            sheet_active[row][5].value = sum(weapon_price)
            row + 1
```

Каким образом это должно выглядеть в excel:

```
    ITEM         Quantity                          Price
Silver Sword        3 #+1 за каждый найденный       0.2 # Просто цена, либо цена всех найденных предметов по названию. (не сильно важно)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом это лучше сделать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
     "Title": "Silver Sword",
     "Offer": {
         "OfferID": "111",
         "Price": {
             "Currency": "Gold",
             "Amount": 0.1
         },
         "Fee": 'null',
         "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
     },
     "MarketPrice": 'null',
     "InstantPrice": 'null',
     "ClassID": "0:222"
     }, {"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
         "Title": "Silver Sword",
         "Offer": {
             "OfferID": "111",
             "Price": {
                 "Currency": "Gold",
                 "Amount": 0.2
             },
             "Fee": 'null',
             "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
         },
         "MarketPrice": 'null',
         "InstantPrice": 'null',
         "ClassID": "0:222"
         }, {"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
             "Title": "Silver Sword",
             "Offer": {
                 "OfferID": "111",
                 "Price": {
                     "Currency": "Gold",
                     "Amount": 0.3
                 },
                 "Fee": 'null',
                 "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
             },
             "MarketPrice": 'null',
             "InstantPrice": 'null',
             "ClassID": "0:222"
             }, {"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
                 "Title": "Silver Sword",
                 "Offer": {
                     "OfferID": "111",
                     "Price": {
                         "Currency": "Gold",
                         "Amount": 0.4
                     },
                     "Fee": 'null',
                     "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
                 },
                 "MarketPrice": 'null',
                 "InstantPrice": 'null',
                 "ClassID": "0:222"
                 }, {"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
                     "Title": "Silver Sword 1",
                     "Offer": {
                         "OfferID": "111",
                         "Price": {
                             "Currency": "Gold",
                             "Amount": 0.4
                         },
                         "Fee": 'null',
                         "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
                     },
                     "MarketPrice": 'null',
                     "InstantPrice": 'null',
                     "ClassID": "0:222"
                     }, {"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
                         "Title": "Silver Sword 1",
                         "Offer": {
                             "OfferID": "111",
                             "Price": {
                                 "Currency": "Gold",
                                 "Amount": 0.4
                             },
                             "Fee": 'null',
                             "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
                         },
                         "MarketPrice": 'null',
                         "InstantPrice": 'null',
                         "ClassID": "0:222"
                         }, {"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
                             "Title": "Silver Sword 2",
                             "Offer": {
                                 "OfferID": "111",
                                 "Price": {
                                     "Currency": "Gold",
                                     "Amount": 0.7
                                 },
                                 "Fee": 'null',
                                 "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
                             },
                             "MarketPrice": 'null',
                             "InstantPrice": 'null',
                             "ClassID": "0:222"
                             }, {"AssetID": "1452cdc-2839-543e6-892a-c86356e4bb558",
                                 "Title": "Silver Sword 2",
                                 "Offer": {
                                     "OfferID": "111",
                                     "Price": {
                                         "Currency": "Gold",
                                         "Amount": 0.6
                                     },
                                     "Fee": 'null',
                                     "CreatedDate": "1623766719"
                                 },
                                 "MarketPrice": 'null',
                                 "InstantPrice": 'null',
                                 "ClassID": "0:222"
                                 }

x = []  # создадим новый список
for i in a:  # пройдёмся циклом по всем элементам
    x.append({i['Title']: i['Offer']['Price']['Amount']})  # добавим в список словарь вида {Title: Amount}
    
print(x)

y = {}
for b in x:
    for d, e in b.items():
        if d in y:  # если ключ (Title) уже есть в словаре
            y[d] += e  # прибавим к значению (Amount)
        else:
            y[d] = e  # иначе добавим пару ключ: значение

print(y)
print('количество предметов:', len(y.items()))
print('общая стоимость предметов:', sum(y.values()))

[{'Silver Sword': 0.1}, {'Silver Sword': 0.2}, {'Silver Sword': 0.3}, {'Silver Sword': 0.4}, {'Silver Sword 1': 0.4}, {'Silver Sword 1': 0.4}, {'Silver Sword 2': 0.7}, {'Silver Sword 2': 0.6}]

{'Silver Sword': 1.0, 'Silver Sword 1': 0.8, 'Silver Sword 2': 1.2999999999999998}
количество предметов: 3
общая стоимость предметов: 3.0999999999999996
```

Comment: Благодарен! Подскажите ещё пожалуйста, как можно вывести количество одинаковых предметов? К примеру [Silver Sword] [3] (не общая сумма названий предметов, а количество данного предмета найденного в списке), [Silver Sword 1] [2]?

Comment: `len(i['Title'])`. Если ответ является решением вашего вопроса, отметьте его таковым, это поможет другим участникам.

Comment: К сожалению не понял вашего комментария... len возвращает длину строки. В данном случае 12 (Silver Sword).

Comment: Возможно я неправильно рассказал о проблеме. Мне приходят ответы "одинаковые". Т.е Silver Sword, Golds Sword, Silver Bow в title может прийти в количестве 500 штук. Мне хотелось бы посчитать количество каждого предмета:
Silver Sword количество 340,
Gold Sword количество 100,
SIlver Bow количество 145.

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/16406329/python-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5